# custom framework library(classes-full-debug.jar) in android-studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

My application run on custom android-board.
So has custom framework library.

In eclipse using below
Properties for project -> Java Build Path -> add external jar (SDK/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVKm3.png

I'm can't find solution in Android-studio 1.0.1
I try added dependencies
provided files('/home/voider/work/G5new/binary/dtv/classes-full-debug.jar')
but can not resolve added function.

Thanks